# How to cut and overwrite a certain section from a file BASH

Tags: bash, grep

How to cut and overwrite a certain section from a file BASH

Content in dl.txt: "127. www.example.com"

I have tried:

```
#cat dl.txt|egrep -v "^[0-9]+.[ ]" > dl.txt
#cat dl.txt|egrep "www.example.com" > dl.txt
```

Could this maybe be done in awk ?

Comment: What is your example output?

Comment: Cut and overwrite with what?

Comment: what must be dl.txt after command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to alter the contents of the file `dl.txt` and delete "127. ", you can use sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/127. //' dl.txt
```

Then you will see that `dl.txt` is changed and `dl.txt.bak` is a backup copy.

Likewise if you want to remove the "www.example.com"

```
sed -i.bak 's/www.example.com//' dl.txt
```

Or if you want to delete everything up to, and including the space on each line:

```
sed -i.bak 's/.* //' dl.txt
```

Or using awk:

```
awk '{print $1}' dl.txt
127.

awk '{print $2}' dl.txt
www.example.com
```

Or you can do it nearly in-place with awk like this, only overwriting the original if the awk is successful:

```
awk '{print $2}' dl.txt > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp dl.txt
```

Comment: Pleasure. Please accept it so I get a lovely big green tick :-)

Answer (score 0):

Below should get rid of 127. before the url, or any ip address for that matter:

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\+\.\?\s*//g' dl.txt
```

Comment: (1) Useless use of cat.  (2) You are truncating the input file.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to look at my post (:. This was what I was trying to do